# What would be the best practice with multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scalability

I need to build a SAS application, part is MySQL (containing customer information and data etc.) the other part is on MongoDB as it uses great ammounts of quite raw unrelated data, which is subject to MapReduce and Aggregation. It would be highly inefficient to use just one of the two, so I have to use them both. The scenario summary would be like this, I have a table in the MySQL db with customer accounts, under which I have actual users. The relevant one is the customer_id. Now, each customer has particular formatted data in the MongoDB side so I would require collection sets for each of the customers, example 31filters,31data,31logs where 31 would be the customer id, all these collections are to reside in the same mongodb database. Is this an acceptable approach or it would be better to actually have separate mongodbdatabases for each customer? What would be the best approach in terms of scalability?

Thank you

Comment: How many customers? Typically I'd keep the customers all together and similar data in one collection, so you'd have `filters`, `logs`, `data` collections.

Comment: I can't keep all data in one collection as there are highly different data structures, each customer has a collection of filters, a collection of data (extended profiles on which the predefined filters run), and also filter sets. Keeping different structures of data in one collection seems odd to me and also I try to avoid having very large documents, the customers might be thousands.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question - if the data is so different per customer it would be inappropriate to mix data from different customers, you should use separate databases for each set of customer data.